# Video files on Samba drives don't play on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: video, samba

I have a couple boxes that share drives via Samba.  They're were all on Ubuntu 22.04 until I upgraded one to 22.10 (on a clean, formatted drive).  I mount the drives with a line:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o user=larry,pass=XXX,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=1.0 //10.0.0.23/Misc   /smb/fs1/Misc`

Note: I've also tried without the "vers=1.0"

On the 22.10 system, all video files (mp4, avi, wmv) are all unplayble in both SMPlayer and the built-in video player - both take an error, then stop.  Every other file type seems fine, jpg, txt, mp3

Is there something set wrong preventing videos playing?